# Join tables using max(column) with a with another column >0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables that I’m trying to build a query with for our fundraising department but that I’m struggling with.  Using SQL Server 2008.

The Appeals table holds data about which members we are going to send an appeal for a donation to.

The Yearly_Gift table holds data about how much money a member donated on a yearly basis.  Sometimes this table can have a zero dollar amount for a specific year.

What I’m trying to do is use these two tables to come up with the last year that someone donated and how much they donated, provided that it was greater than zero, for the appeal we are sending out.

Here are simplified versions of the tables and some data.   I’m also including my desired output.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
--Build Tables

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appeals](
    [Appeal_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Member_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Appeals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Appeal_ID] ASC,
    [Member_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY     =     OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Yearly_Gift](
    [Member_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FiscalYear] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Yearly_Gift] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Member_ID] ASC,
    [FiscalYear] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
 STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
 IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


--Fill tables

INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (1,101)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (1,102)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (2,101)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (2,102)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (2,103)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (2,104)
INSERT INTO Appeals VALUES (2,105)

INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(101,'2015',100)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(102,'2014',0)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(102,'2012',150)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(102,'2011',200)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(103,'2013',500)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(103,'2014',500)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(104,'2012',200)
INSERT INTO Yearly_Gift VALUES(104,'2015',100)
```

**Desired Output**

```
Appeal_ID  Member_ID  FiscalYear  Amount
2          101         2015       100
2          102         2012       150
2          103         2014       500   
2          104         2015       100 
2          105         NULL       NULL
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: why `101` has `appeal 1 and 2`?

Comment: One member can belong to many appeals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH X AS
(
    SELECT A.[Appeal_ID], A.[Member_ID],Y.[FiscalYear], Y.[Amount] 
    FROM [dbo].[Appeals] A
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Yearly_Gift] Y ON Y.[Member_ID] = A.[Member_ID]
)
SELECT X.[Appeal_ID], X.[Member_ID],Y.[FiscalYear], X.[Amount] 
FROM X
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Member_ID], 
    MAX([FiscalYear]) AS [FiscalYear] , 
    MAX([Appeal_ID]) AS [Appeal_ID]
    FROM X 
    WHERE Amount > 0
    GROUP BY X.[Member_ID]
) Y ON X.Appeal_ID = Y.Appeal_ID AND X.Member_ID = Y.Member_ID AND X.FiscalYear = Y.FiscalYear
WHERE Y.[FiscalYear] IS NULL AND  X.[Amount]  IS NULL OR Y.[FiscalYear] IS NOT NULL AND  X.[Amount]  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY X.Appeal_ID,X.Member_ID
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you every one for you help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Select a.Appeal_ID, a.Member_ID, y.FiscalYear, y.Amount
  From Appeals a INNER JOIN Yearly_Gift y ON a.Member_ID = y.Member_ID
  where y.Amount > 0 AND y.FiscalYear = 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
     SELECT Appeal_ID,  A.Member_ID,  FiscalYear,  Amount,
            row_number() over (partition by A.Member_ID order by FiscalYear  DESC) as rn
     FROM Appeals A
     LEFT JOIN Yearly_Gift Y  
            ON A.Member_ID = Y.Member_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
  AND Amount <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - this query is a bit long/ugly, but it works. If I had more time, I'd look into optimizations and code reduction.

```
SELECT
  target_members.Appeal_ID, target_members.Member_ID, FiscalYear, Amount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      MAX( Appeal_ID ) AS Appeal_ID,
      Member_ID
    FROM
      Appeals
    GROUP BY
      Member_ID
  ) AS target_members
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX( Appeals.Appeal_ID ) AS Appeal_ID,
      Yearly_Gift.Member_ID,
      Yearly_Gift.FiscalYear,
      Yearly_Gift.Amount,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Yearly_Gift.Member_ID ORDER BY FiscalYear DESC ) AS r
    FROM
      Appeals,
      Yearly_Gift
    WHERE
      Yearly_Gift.Member_ID = Appeals.Member_ID AND
      Amount > 0
    GROUP BY
      Yearly_Gift.Member_ID,
      Yearly_Gift.FiscalYear,
      Yearly_Gift.Amount
  ) AS last_donation
  ON last_donation.Appeal_ID = target_members.Appeal_ID AND
     last_donation.Member_ID = target_members.Member_ID AND
     r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      SELECT  MAX(A.APPEAL_ID),  A. MEMBER_ID, B. FISCAL_YEAR,B.AMOUNT
      FROM XX_APPEALS A  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT Y.MEMBER_ID, Y.FISCAL_YEAR, Y.AMOUNT
         FROM XX_YEARLY_GIFT Y, -- select all columns in yearly_gift
           (                    -- that match the latest year per member
            SELECT MEMBER_ID, MAX(FISCAL_YEAR) LATEST_YEAR
            FROM XX_YEARLY_GIFT
            GROUP BY MEMBER_ID  --find latest year of giving per member
            ) S
           WHERE Y.MEMBER_ID = S.MEMBER_ID
           AND Y.FISCAL_YEAR = S.LATEST_YEAR
           ORDER BY Y.MEMBER_ID   
         ) B
     ON  A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID
     GROUP BY A. MEMBER_ID, B. FISCAL_YEAR,B.AMOUNT
     ORDER BY A.MEMBER_ID
```

This could also  be adapted to report back by largest gift instead of most recent, or report back most recent and recent_year, together with largest_gift.